# Image.onload not executing all code

Tags: javascript, onload

I have this piece of javascript that is taking several images and waiting for them all to load to then performs some logic on them. This is a stripped out piece of code that is still not doing what is expected:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var art = new Image();
    var top_image = new Image();
    var bottom_image = new Image();
    var left_image = new Image();
    var right_image = new Image();

    art.onload = function() {
        console.log("1");
        top_image.onload = function() {
            console.log("2");
            bottom_image.onload = function() {
                console.log("3");
                right_image.onload = function() {
                    console.log("4");
                    left_image.onload = function() {
                        console.log("5");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    art.src = 'images/prototype.jpg';
    top_image.src = 'images/2_4_top_center.png';
    bottom_image.src = 'images/2_4_bottom_center.png';
    right_image.src = 'images/2_4_middle_right.png';
    left_image.src = 'images/2_4_middle_left.png';
});
```

The problem is that when I hard reload the browser a seemingly random number logs appear in the console. It mostly only logs "1" but sometimes gets all the way to logging "5". I'm not sure what's happening here and why it only behaves as expected sometimes.

Comment: The images are not guaranteed to load in the order you have specified when setting the `src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just append an onclick handler to `top_image` when `art` has already loaded, therefore if `top_image` loads before `art`, the second handler would not be triggered. To solve this, attach handlers to all images before you set their source, and use promises to handle them:

```
   const onload = img => new Promise(res => img.onload = res);

  var art = new Image();
  var top_image = new Image();
  var bottom_image = new Image();
  var left_image = new Image();
  var right_image = new Image();

  Promise.all([art, top_image, bottom_image, left_image, right_image].map(onload))
    .then(() => {
       // All loaded !!
    });

  // Add sources
```